# Strange behavior jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I use Jinja2, as template engine, but noticed with a strange behavior for me.
Here is my code:

```
<ol>
{% for i in range(1, n) %}
    {% if i % 15 == 0 %}
        <li>FizzBuzz</li>
    {% elif i % 3 == 0 %}
        <li>Fizz</li>
    {% elif i % 5 == 0 %}
        <li>Buzz</li>
    {% else %}
        <li>{{ i }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

`<li>` after the FizzBuzz empty.

That's not quite what I wanted.
If I just change the code, then all will be well:

```
<ol>
{% for i in range(1, n) %}
    <li>
    {% if i % 15 == 0 %}
        FizzBuzz
    {% elif i % 3 == 0 %}
        Fizz
    {% elif i % 5 == 0 %}
        Buzz
    {% else %}
        {{ i }}
    {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

But I do not understand why the first code does not work properly. Can anybody explain? Thank you!

Comment: Can you include the *textual output* of the template?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue at all. The first template *works just fine* for me. No empty `<li>` tags are produced.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe this behavior is specific to the version that is a part of Google Could.